# Selenium.WebDriver with portable FireFox c#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I need to start Selenium with Firefox Portable.
If I start Firefox.exe portable with doublé clic, it starts.
The path to Firefox.exe is correct: A FireFoxPortable folder inside Debug project's folder.

This is the code I use:

```
var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = 
    Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "FireFoxPortable",
        "FireFox.exe");
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

var options = new FirefoxOptions();
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Creating the driver I have an exception -> Cannot find Firefox binary in PATH or default install locations. Make sure Firefox is installed. OS appears to be: Vista

I try this variant, but no work:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService);
```

I'm using this nuget packages:
[image: Nuget packages]

Is this the correct way?

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE ---------------------------------------------**

With this code Works:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    "FireFoxPortable", "FireFox.exe");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(path),profile);
```

But a Warning for new FirefoxDriver Shown: **FirefoxDriver should not be constructed with a FirefoxBinary object. Use FirefoxOptions instead. This constructor will be removed in a future release.'**

What's the correct way?

Comment: Are you using geckodriver?

Comment: try this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23568/how-to-get-c-to-initialize-geckodriver

Comment: No work! :( Maybe is my portable download. Any secure link to download a Firefox portable edition?

Comment: I installed Firefox in my computer and copied Firefox folder to Portable folder and it Works. I uninstalled Firefox and it didn't work! (launch Firefox.exe with doublé clic Works)